# Accessing sys.sql_modules in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following query lists all stored procedures in a database along with their definition. It returns 12 rows:

```
USE [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME (object_id) AS sp_name, 
       [definition] AS sp_definition
FROM [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO].sys.sql_modules as st
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

When I change the first line of the query to use a different database:

```
USE [HQ-193-STOCK-DBO]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME (object_id) AS sp_name, 
       [definition] AS sp_definition
FROM [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO].sys.sql_modules as st
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

Zero rows returned.

When I now change the 4th line of the query (the FROM line):

```
USE [HQ-193-STOCK-DBO]

SELECT OBJECT_NAME (object_id) AS sp_name, 
       [definition] AS sp_definition
FROM [HQ-193-STOCK-DBO].sys.sql_modules as st
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY (object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

I get one row returned.

It appears that prefixing `sys.sql_modules` with the database name does not work as I expected.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? Why can't I specify the db name when referring to `sys.sql_modules`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OBJECT_NAME()` and `OBJECTPROPERTY()` look at the current database. Stop using them. Usually you will get no match (which makes your `WHERE` clause return 0 rows in the second query - you can confirm this by just returning `object_id`, and then checking the current database's `sys.objects` for any of those values), but sometimes you might get the *wrong* match if you happen to have the same `object_id` for objects in both databases.

([They also ignore isolation semantics, so can be completely blocked by other queries, even if you are using `READ UNCOMMITTED / NOLOCK`](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432497/metadata-functions-should-follow-same-isolation-semantics-as-metadata-queries). So even in the *same* database, I highly recommend using joins to the other catalog views instead of the helper metadata functions. Usually it's not a problem, but they'll get blocked at the most inopportune times, I promise.)

Instead, you can say:

```
SELECT o.name AS sp_name, st.[definition] AS sp_definition
FROM [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO].sys.sql_modules as st
INNER JOIN [HQ-211-STOCK-DBO].sys.objects AS o
ON st.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.type = 'P';
```